# STORING IMAGE using MediaStore.Images.media to save in a particular folder

Tags: java, android, mediastore

I have to save a bitmap in a particular folder. If the folder is not created, I want to create it.

I know you can just save an image like that:

```
 MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap,       
                 bitmap + ".jpg Card Image", bitmap + ".jpg Card Image");
```

But how can I save it in a specific location like "MediaStore/folder"(Don't actually know how the path should be) where folder is a folder that I want to create (if it's not created).

I've tried a lot of things and they didn't work so I would be very thankful if someone could help me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use internal storage like so if you're willing to not use MediaStore

```
void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File dir = getFilesDir(); // or getCacheDir()
    if (!new File(dir + "/folderName").isDirectory()) {
        if (new File(dir + "/folderName").mkdir()) { // directory made successfully
            dir = new File(dir + "/folderName/" + "fileName.ext");
        } else { // error making the directory
            return;
        }
    } else {
        dir = new File(dir + "/folderName/" + "fileName.ext");
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dir);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To retrieve the bitmap

```
Bitmap loadBitmap(File dir) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(dir);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Where does this store the folder?

Comment: In the app's data directory. This means the folder will be removed when the app is uninstalled.

Comment: And can I put the data where the user can acces it and where if the app get uninstalled, the folder doesn't get removed?

Comment: Not using this method, no. The data will be erased when the app is uninstalled as the directories returned by getFilesDir() and getCacheDir() are specific to that app.